# Side-by-side plots in Shiny Quarto document

Tags: r, shiny, quarto

I would like to show two plots side-by-side using `shiny` in a `Quarto` document. We could use a `fluidrow` with two `column`s, but this doesn't seem to work in shiny quarto. Here is some reproducible code:

````
---
format: html
server: shiny
---

```{r}
#| panel: sidebar
sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", 
            min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
```

```{r}
#| panel: fill
fluidRow(
  column(width=4, plotOutput("distPlot")),
  column(width=4, plotOutput("distPlot2"))
)
```

```{r}
#| context: server
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
   x <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
   bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
   hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
        xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
        main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
})
output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
  x <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
   bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
   hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'red', border = 'white',
        xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
        main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
})
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see the plots are shown below each other. I don't understand this because we use a [custom layout](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/layout-guide/) like explained in the link. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to show plots side-by-side in a shiny app in a Quarto document?

Answer (score 0):

I believe https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/layout.html#panel-layout is a more suitable source to follow here. Try with `layout-ncol` :

````
```{r}
#| panel: fill
#| layout-ncol: 2
plotOutput("distPlot")
plotOutput("distPlot2")
```
````

[image]